# uniqueness of identity of a group G

Tags: group-theory

The theorem for uniqueness of identity of a group says there is one identity element $e$ in a group and this element $e$ is unique.

My book states the proof as follows:

$a.e=a$ for all $a \in G$ and

$a.e'=a$ for all $a \in G$

It proceeds by letting $a =e$ and $a =e'$ and what follows is algebraic manipulation.

What is the motivation for letting $a =e$ and $a =e'$?

I tried a different and simple proof as follows:

$a.e = a$ for all $a \in G$ and
$a.e' = a$ for all $a \in G$

Since $a=a$, we have

$a.e = a.e'$

This implies $e=e'$

Is this a legitimate way to demonstrate the proof?

Comment: Your proof is fine, just let $a$ be any element, then $ae=ae'$, so multiply on the left by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on the subtleties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like there is a detail that needs to be explained in your proof.  I get that if $a = a$ then $a\cdot e = a\cdot e'$.  However the next step would be 
$$a^{-1}\cdot a\cdot e = a^{-1}\cdot a\cdot e'$$
Now $a^{-1}\cdot a$ is equal to the identity.  Which one though?

Comment: well, let the inverse a be $$a^-1$$.
Multiplying both sides by $$a^-1$$, we have $$e'=e$$

Comment: @user , muaddib is right: if you let two units exist, then there's an issue with the definition of $a^{-1}$ (it can be avoided, though, but it makes the definition of the inverse less elegant). Fortunately, the standard proof of uniqueness of unit holds for all [magmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29) where a left and a right unit exist (therefore *in maximal generality*), so we never bother with that.